# What are all Financial Industries - Standards, Protocols and Data Model?

Tags: standards, financial, banking

When I was preparing for TOGAF exam, I came across Open Standard available for DataModel, Service Model, Architecture for many industries.

(Example: ARTS has defined a data model for the Retail industry.
Energistics has defined a data model for the Petrotechnical industry.
FPL Defined fix protocol for trading.
SWIFT & ISO has some standard about Interbank Messaging.)

I would like to know from this community
What are all the OpenStandard - "protocol, datamodel, servicemodel" which you work with in Financial Industry? How many of them are really "Open" and widely used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three widely used standards:

- [FIX](http://www.fixprotocol.org/)
- [FpML](http://www.fpml.org/)
- [SWIFT](http://www.swift.com/solutions/standards/index.page?)

Most standards are "member-owned" by organizations like [ISDA](http://www.isda.org/), [SWIFT](http://www.swift.com/about_swift/company_information/index.page?lang=en) or [FPL](http://www.fixprotocol.org/join/) that you can join. Many standards are free as in beer, although the companies usually earn money with reference implementations and other services.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying standard for Financial Services is [ISO 20022](http://www.iso20022.org/). SWIFT, ISDA (FpML), FPL (FIX), and many others are all part of the ISO 20022 community.

ISO 20022 is broad in that it covers all of financial services - from Cards to Regulators.